# Is $ \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})) $ known?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Following my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916155/what-is-the-outer-automorphism-group) about the outer automorphism group, I would like to know if the structure of the automorphism group of the absolute Galois group of the rationals is known. Specifically, is it isomorphic to the cyclic group with two elements ?

Comment: There is no direct description known so far. This contains a few results: http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/CEB/CEBTalk.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the Neukirch–Uchida theorem , Aut(Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$))= Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$).

Comment: Isn't the theorem that $\operatorname{Out}(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})) = \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: @anomaly Every element in Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$) acts by conjugation, which is obvious inner. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean (and algebraic number theory is really not my field). The group $G = \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$ is very nonabelian, so $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is at least not canonically isomorphic to $\operatorname{Out}(G)$.

Comment: @anomaly I'm not familiar with Neukirch-Uchida, but it often happens for a non-abelian group that all its automorphisms are inner. A well known example is the symmetric group $S_n$, $n\ge5$, whose automorphisms are all inner except in the case $n=6$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Certainly; most of the finite (nonabelian) simple groups have trivial or small cyclic outer automorphism groups. I just meant that unless $X$ is abelian, $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Out}(X) = \operatorname{Aut}(X) / \operatorname{Inn}(X)$ are different things, and I think the Neukirch-Uchida theorem refers to the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @anomaly.

Comment: @anomaly In fact Out(Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$))={1}. Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$) is center-free, Aut(Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$))=Inn(Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$))$\cong$Gal($\mathbb{\bar{Q}/Q}$)

Comment: @anomaly You can see a proof of this result in the book "Cohomology of Number Fields" by Neukirch and others.

Comment: @anomaly I'm prepared to be wrong about this (above my level), but I read [the Wikipedia article on Neukirch-Uchida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neukirch%E2%80%93Uchida_theorem) to state that for all number fields $K$ we have $$Aut(K)\simeq Out(Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/K)).$$ With $K=\Bbb{Q}$ this seems to state that $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$ has no outer automorphisms, and given it's centerless, it is isomorphic to its group of inner automorphisms. Basically agreeing with what Z.Zhou claims.

Comment: OK, that makes sense: $G = \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ has $\operatorname{Out}(G)$ trivial (which seems reasonable for such a large, compllicated group) and the result is that $G = \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, not $\operatorname{Out}(G)$. Cool.