# What is an outer automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I know that an automorphism of a group is just an isomorphism of that group with itself. I know that an *inner* automorphism is an isomorphism/automorphism of the form $\phi_g$ where $\phi_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$.

I have heard people talking about an outer automorphism. What are these?

Comment: As far as I know, "outer" means "not inner" in this context.

Comment: The usage is slightly confusing An outer automorphism is an element of $ {\rm Aut}(G) \setminus {\rm Inn}(G)$. But the outer automorphism group is defined to be the quotient group ${\rm Aut}(G)/{\rm Inn}(G)$.

Comment: Is it really necessary to ask when [answers are so easy to find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group)?  *An automorphism of a group which is not inner is called an outer automorphism.*  It also goes on to explain the issue Derek mentions. I don't want to sound antagonistic, but I do want to encourage you to do at least minimal research into your question before asking. We do not need to re-record everything that's easy to find on the internet again on our site...

Comment: Just because an answer is easy to find, it does not follow that the answer is sensible. See my comment to the answer of @HagenvonEitzen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the outer automorphism group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916155/what-is-the-outer-automorphism-group)

Comment: I've [recently][1] found useful to show the things in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. This gives a hint of: firstly, why *inner* automorphisms are named that way; secondly, the difference between the "outer automorphisms" (the region of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ "outside" $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$) and the *outer automorphism (factor) group* (the set of the concentric $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$-wise *annulii* covering the whole $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$).


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097209/visual-representations-of-groups-in-their-symmetric-groups?noredirect=1#comment6396855_3097209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **outer automorphism** is just an automorphism that is not an inner automorphism. But be careful: We know that the group $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ of inner automorphisms is a normal subgroup of the group $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ of all automorphisms of $G$, and the quotient $\operatorname{Out}(G)=\operatorname{Aut}(G)/\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is called the **outer automorphism group**. So confusingly, the elements of the outer automorphism group are *not* outer automorhims, but rather equivalence classes of outer automorphisms ...

Comment: To be pedantic, the non-identity elements of the outer automorphism group are not outer automorphisms but rather ...

Comment: Although it appears that I am fighting a strong tide, I have to register a strong disagreement with this usage of the term "outer automorphism". Using it to mean "an automorphism that is not inner" is really a terrible usage. I would encourage anyone writing about outer automorphism groups to avoid that usage.

Comment: This was really helpful.

Comment: It turns out that many people unfortunately say "outer automorphism" to mean "non-inner automorphism", and there is not even the excuse that "non-inner" is hard to write or pronounce. This is confusing, sure, but is hopelessly frequent. Just search "is an outer automorphism".

Comment: @LeeMosher  If we were to start over, wouldn't it make more sense to keep that usage, but rename $\mathrm{Aut}(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ to something else. After all, why shouldn't an outer automorphism actually be an automorphism, rather than a coset? (I consider both usage more or less entrenched, so on equal footing if we're discussing alternate definitions.)

Comment: One could try to track the first appearance of "outer automorphism" (or its translations in French or German). I'd be very surprised if it were to mean "non-inner". I guess this usage for "non-inner" is originally a confusion between quotients and complement of a subgroup. The notion of non-inner automorphism is not one that deserves a more specific name, nor the notion of non-identity element in a group.